# Azure Devops ReplaceTokensV5 is not working as expected

Tags: azure-devops, environment-variables

I'm triying to assign variables just before the deployment in my Azure Pipeline, like I need different variable definations for every release so it is just before the deployment.

[image]

Here is the task that i do that,

[image]

but even it detects the yaml it gives me this output so not a single token is changed.

```
2023-12-20T00:28:28.6433109Z replaced 0 tokens out of 0 in 1 file(s) in 0.011 seconds.
```

here is a sample defination that i wanna change in target yaml

```
image: {{IMAGE_NAME}}
```

I use same task also inside of yaml for Artifact build for some other variables it works but doesn't during last stage.

Comment: Hi there, Since you have added an answer below, may I know if the issue is resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I did was enabling keep missing token option in UI, somehow it’s losing the variables when you use the function both in pipeline and release yaml.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, I generated a release pipeline demo and the `replacetokens@5` task worked to replace `{{IMAGE_NAME}}` in the `azure-deployment.yaml` file with the vaules of the variables `IMAGE_NAME` from **different** stages in  my release pipeline.

Since you mentioned the replacement didn't work only in the last stage, you may probably need to confirm the variable was defined in the correct stage scope. If the variable `IMAGE_NAME` was retrieved from any of your variable groups in the pipeline library, you need to double check the scope of the linked variable group(s) as well and avoid defining conflicting/duplicate variables in the same scope.

[image]